# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict

Tags: python, json, api, get, request

This is my code:

```
from os import rename, write
import requests
import json

url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=%7Bquery%7D%7B&page,per_page,sort,order%7D"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data)

outfile = open("C:/Users/vladi/Desktop/json files Vlad/file structure first attemp.json", "r")
json_object = json.load(outfile)

with open(data,'w') as endfile:
    endfile.write(json_object)
    print(endfile)
```

I want to call API request.
I want to take data from this URL: `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=%7Bquery%7D%7B&page,per_page,sort,order%7D`,
and rewrite it with my own data which is my file called `file structure first attemp.json`
and update this URL with my own data.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

url = "https://api.github.com/search/usersq=%7Bquery%7D%7B&page,per_page,sort,order%7D"

data = requests.get(url)

with open(data,'w') as endfile:
    endfile.write(data.text)
```

- `json.loads()` returns a Python dictionary, which cannot be written to a file. Simply write the returned string from the URL.
- `response.json()` is a built in feature that `requests` uses to load the JSON returned from the URL. So you are loading the JSON twice.